# std::unique_lock and std::shared_lock in same thread - shouldn't work, but does?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, mutex

Why is it possible to acquire two different locks on a `std::shared_mutex`?

The following code

```
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <iostream>

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/[]) {
    std::shared_mutex mut;
    std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> ulock{mut};
    if(ulock)
        std::cout << "uniqe_lock is bool true\n";
    if(ulock.owns_lock())
        std::cout << "uniqe_lock owns lock\n";
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> slock{mut};
    if(slock)
        std::cout << "shared_lock is bool true\n";
    if(slock.owns_lock())
        std::cout << "shared_lock owns lock\n";
}
```

when compiled with a `g++` 9.4.0 (current available on Ubuntu 20.04.1)

```
g++ -std=c++17 mutex.cpp
```

outputs all `cout` lines. I.e. the thread acquires **both** the `unique_lock` **and** the `shared_lock`. As I understand [`cppreference` on the `shared_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex), acquiring the second lock should fail while the first one is still alive.

> "Within one thread, only one lock (shared or exclusive) can be acquired at the same time."

What do I miss here? Why can the `shared_lock` be acquired even with the previous `unique_lock` still active?

Comment: You have only one thread...

Comment: @kaba A thread locking a `std::shared_mutex` that it already has a lock on is Undefined Behavior. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex/lock) : "If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex in any mode (shared or exclusive), the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Al right, thanks, that was the part I missed (so the sentence I quoted now seems a bit misleading to me). The fact you hinted on, also holds the other way around (i.e. is stated for `lock_shared` as well).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Also from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex/lock_shared): "If `lock_shared` is called by a thread that already owns the mutex in any mode (exclusive or shared), the behavior is undefined."

You have UB; the toolchain is not required to diagnose this, though it might if you enabled your stdlib's debug mode (`_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` for libstdc++).